# Matching timestamps from git log with bash regex

Tags: regex, git, bash

I am writing a script to convert my git log into google calendar format.
But when I check the calendar.txt file it only has the initial header line.

I used this regex manually in sublime and it worked perfectly. So there must be something wrong with my bash syntax.

```
#! /bin/bash
# add git log
git log --date=iso --pretty=format:"%ad%x09%s" > calendartmp.txt

# add header line to beginning of file
echo "Start Date,Start Time,Subject" > calendar.txt

#parse line by line into correct format
# "\d\d(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d) ([\d+\:]+) .*\t(.*)" -> "$2/$3/$1,$4,$5"

while read p; do
  [[ $p =~ \d\d(\d\d)\-(\d\d)\-(\d\d)\ (\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d).*\t(.*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}/${BASH_REMATCH[1]},${BASH_REMATCH[4]},${BASH_REMATCH[5]}" >> calendar.txt
done < calendartmp.txt

#delete temp file
rm calendartmp.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d` is PCRE, not POSIX ERE (which is the regex syntax used by bash). Use `[[:digit:]]` to match a digit in an ERE-compatible way.

Or you could just do the date parsing and reformatting a different way entirely. Personally, if you had GNU date, I'd use that.

```
{
  echo "Start Date,Start Time,Subject"
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r date data; do
    printf '%s,%s' "$(date --date="$date" +%m/%d/%Y,%H:%M:%S)" "$data"
  done
} < <(git log --date=iso --pretty='%ad%x09%s') \
  >calendar.txt
```

You'll also notice that this version requires no temporary files, and opens calendar.txt for output only once, rather than reopening it every time you want to do a single-line write.